# Do different language editions of Lonely Planet contain different content?

Tags: languages, guidebooks

I'm planning to travel to Spain when things have improved a bit, and I'm getting reasonably good at reading Spanish, and my wife is a native speaker. I'm thinking of getting guidebooks in Spanish as well as in English.

When Lonely Planet has guides in other languages ([ironically enough](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/europe-western-europe/spain/spain-lonely-planet-guide-edition-in-spanish), there doesn't seem to be a Spanish-language Lonely Planet guide to [Spain as a whole](https://www.lonelyplanet.es/tienda/guias/destinos/europa/espana)), do they tend to be the same content just translated, or do they tend to be modified to suit the audience, with the local language editions being less (or more) "touristy"? Also, is Lonely Planet the dominant guidebook publisher for Spanish?

Comment: Fun fact I once met some Germans in Brazil and we both had copies of the LP guide in our respective languages.  Each copy had the same photo on the front cover (a woman carnival dancer) but the image was reversed between them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, they are different.  The different language editions of Lonely Planet are essentially franchised, and while most books are based on English originals, they have considerable leeway to alter the content.

There are also some LP guides that exist *only* in other languages, eg. all the province-level guides to China like this Sichuan/Chongqing guide: [https://www.amazon.com/Lonely-Planet-Travel-Guide-Chongqing/dp/B00DXXBW1M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DXXBW1M)